# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined $scope not working properly with input text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I'm trying to retrieve the passenger.firstName from the form data from view to controller.js using `$scope.passenger.firstName`. But each time I get the following error in console: What could be the problem?

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.proceedARS (controller.js:2138)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14819), <anonymous>:4:221)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15908)
    at callback (angular.js:25887)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17684)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17784)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25892)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13922
```

The view jsp is as below:
It takes the passenger.firstName from the form field and on button click ng-click redirects it to the `proceedARS()` function in the controller.js. But when I click the `{{loadingButtonProceed}}` it simply calls the `loadingFunction()` and keeps showing the loading sign and gets stuck.

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="passenger in passengerList track by $index">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h4 class="text-primary">
                                            <strong>Passenger Details</strong>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label for="">Type  <font color="red">*</font><select type="text"
                                            ng-model="passenger.paxType" class="form-control-sm" ng-disabled="true">
                                                <option value="ADULT" ng-selected="passenger.paxType == 'ADULT'" >Adult</option>
                                                <option value="CHILD" ng-selected="passenger.paxType == 'CHILD'">Child</option>
                                                <!-- <option value="INFANT">Infant</option> -->
                                        </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label for="">Title  <font color="red">*</font><select type="text"
                                            ng-model="passenger.title" class="form-control-sm">
                                                <option value="Mister">Mr.</option>
                                                <option value="Miss">Ms.</option>
                                                <option value="Mrs" ng-show="passenger.paxType == 'ADULT' " >Mrs.</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </label>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label for="">First Name  <font color="red">*</font><input type="text"
                                            ng-model="passenger.firstName" class="form-control-sm"></label><br>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label for="">Last Name  <font color="red">*</font><input type="text"
                                            ng-model="passenger.lastName" class="form-control-sm"></label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="">Nationality  <font color="red">*</font><select type="text"
                                            ng-model="passenger.nationality" class="form-control-sm">
                                                <option value="" selected disabled>Select
                                                    Nationality</option>
                                                    <option value="NP">Nepalese</option>
                                                    <option value="IN">Indian</option>

                                                <%-- <c:forEach var="nationality" items="${nationality}">
                                                    <option value="NP">${nationality}</option>
                                                </c:forEach> --%>
                                        </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <label for="">Remarks <input type="text"
                                            ng-model="passenger.paxRemarks" class="form-control-sm">
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divider-h"></div>



                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default">+ Add Passenger</button> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="proceedARS()">{{loadingButtonProceed}}</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <div class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="backToSecondARS()">Back</button>
                    </div> -->

                    <div class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="newPayment()">Abort</button>
                    </div>
```

The controller.js is as below:

```
$scope.proceedARS = function () {
        $scope.ARSMessage = '';
        //$scope.passenger = {firstName, lastName};
        if ($scope.contactName === undefined || $scope.contactName === null || $scope.contactName === "") {
            $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
            console.log("Error from contactName");
            return;
        }

        if ($scope.contactEmail === undefined || $scope.contactEmail === null || $scope.contactEmail === "") {
            $scope.contactEmail = "";
            console.log("Error from contactEmail");
        }

        if ($scope.contactNumber === undefined || $scope.contactNumber === null || $scope.contactNumber === "") {
            $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
            console.log("Error from contactNumber");
            return;
        }

       if ($scope.passenger.firstName === undefined || $scope.passenger.firstName === null || $scope.passenger.firstName === "") {
            $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
            console.log("Error from P firstName");
        }

        if ($scope.passenger.lastName === undefined || $scope.passenger.lastName === null || $scope.passenger.lastName === "") {
            $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
            console.log("Error from P lastName");
        }

        if ($scope.passenger.nationality === undefined || $scope.passenger.nationality === null || $scope.passenger.nationality === "") {
            $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
            console.log("Error from P nationality");
        }

        if ($scope.contactNumber.length != 9 && $scope.contactNumber.length != 10) {
            $scope.ARSMessage = 'Contact Number Length Invalid';
            return;
        }

        if ($scope.selectedOutbound == undefined || $scope.selectedOutbound == "" || $scope.selectedOutbound == null) {
            $scope.ARSMessage = "Please select one of the flights for departure";
            return;
        }

        if ($scope.flightAvailability.tripType == 'R') {
            if ($scope.selectedInbound == undefined || $scope.selectedInbound == "" || $scope.selectedInbound == null) {
                $scope.ARSMessage = "Please select one of the flights for arrival";
                return;
            }
        }
        $scope.loadingFunction();
        // console.log("Total size: " + $scope.size);
        var outBoundFlightId = $scope.selectedOutbound.flightId;
        var totalAmountOutBound = $scope.selectedOutbound.adultFare * $scope.selectedOutbound.adult * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.childFare * $scope.selectedOutbound.child * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.infantFare * $scope.selectedOutbound.infant * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.fuelSurcharge * $scope.size * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.tax * $scope.size * 1;
        var taxOutBound = $scope.selectedOutbound.tax * $scope.size * 1;
        var agencyCOutBound = $scope.selectedOutbound.agencyCommission * $scope.size * 1;
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$scope.passenger`? Note the `passenger` from your ng-repeat does not get set to the `$scope` object

Comment: Initialize `$scope.passenger = {}`.

Comment: You have an `ng-repeat`, which prints multiple forms. You don't have a method for pulling out the data from a specific form. Find a way to **select** the form (by `index`) and then access the _passenger_ from the global array - `passengerList[index]`

Comment: @PatrickEvans @KaustubhKhare, it's initialised in `ng-repeat="passenger in passengerList"`, so his syntax of pulling out the `ng-model` (per input filed) is wrong

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Can you suggest me a correct way please?

Comment: @Bik is your `loadingButtonProceed` button repeated for every passenger? if yes, you can pass them as a parameter: `ng-click="proceedARS(passenger)"` and use `passenger.firstName` instead of `$scope.passenger.firstName`, etc. Otherwise you need to work with `passengerList` array, and calculate everything in a loop (per passenger)

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, pass passenger object on ng-click like below,

In Html,

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="proceedARS(passenger)">{{loadingButtonProceed}}</button>
```

In Controller,

```
$scope.proceedARS = function (passenger) {

    $scope.ARSMessage = '';

    $scope.passenger = passenger;

    if ($scope.contactName === undefined || $scope.contactName === null || $scope.contactName === "") {
        $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
        console.log("Error from contactName");
        return;
    }

    if ($scope.contactEmail === undefined || $scope.contactEmail === null || $scope.contactEmail === "") {
        $scope.contactEmail = "";
        console.log("Error from contactEmail");
    }

    if ($scope.contactNumber === undefined || $scope.contactNumber === null || $scope.contactNumber === "") {
        $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
        console.log("Error from contactNumber");
        return;
    }

   if ($scope.passenger.firstName === undefined || $scope.passenger.firstName === null || $scope.passenger.firstName === "") {
        $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
        console.log("Error from P firstName");
    }

    if ($scope.passenger.lastName === undefined || $scope.passenger.lastName === null || $scope.passenger.lastName === "") {
        $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
        console.log("Error from P lastName");
    }

    if ($scope.passenger.nationality === undefined || $scope.passenger.nationality === null || $scope.passenger.nationality === "") {
        $scope.ARSMessage = 'Please fill all the required fields';
        console.log("Error from P nationality");
    }

    if ($scope.contactNumber.length != 9 && $scope.contactNumber.length != 10) {
        $scope.ARSMessage = 'Contact Number Length Invalid';
        return;
    }

    if ($scope.selectedOutbound == undefined || $scope.selectedOutbound == "" || $scope.selectedOutbound == null) {
        $scope.ARSMessage = "Please select one of the flights for departure";
        return;
    }

    if ($scope.flightAvailability.tripType == 'R') {
        if ($scope.selectedInbound == undefined || $scope.selectedInbound == "" || $scope.selectedInbound == null) {
            $scope.ARSMessage = "Please select one of the flights for arrival";
            return;
        }
    }
    $scope.loadingFunction();
    // console.log("Total size: " + $scope.size);
    var outBoundFlightId = $scope.selectedOutbound.flightId;
    var totalAmountOutBound = $scope.selectedOutbound.adultFare * $scope.selectedOutbound.adult * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.childFare * $scope.selectedOutbound.child * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.infantFare * $scope.selectedOutbound.infant * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.fuelSurcharge * $scope.size * 1 + $scope.selectedOutbound.tax * $scope.size * 1;
    var taxOutBound = $scope.selectedOutbound.tax * $scope.size * 1;
    var agencyCOutBound = $scope.selectedOutbound.agencyCommission * $scope.size * 1;
```